# zsh declare PROMPT using multiple lines

Tags: variables, zsh, prompt

I would like to declare my ZSH prompt using multiple lines and comments, something like:

```
PROMPT="
    %n       # username
    @
    %m       # hostname
    \        # space
    %~       # directory
    $
    \        # space
"
```

(e.g. something like perl regex's "ignore whitespace mode")

I could swear I used to do something like this, but cannot find those old files any longer. I have searched for variations of "zsh declare prompt across multiple lines" but haven't quite found it.

I know that I can use \ for line continuation, but then we end up with newlines and whitespaces.

edit: Maybe I am misremembering about comments - here is an [example without comments](https://github.com/MrElendig/dotfiles-alice/blob/master/.zshrc#L147).

Comment: Since the `#` in your code are inside a string, they don't introduce comments, but are literal part of the string. There is nothing in zsh like _ignore whitespace_ as in Perl Regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but you don't need to define `PROMPT` in a single assignment:

```
PROMPT="%n"    # username
PROMPT+="@%m"  # @hostname
PROMPT+=" %~"  # directory
PROMPT+="$ "
```

Probably closer to what you wanted is the ability to join the elements of an array:

```
prompt_components=(
   %n   # username
   " "  # space
   %m   # hostname
   " "  # space
   "%~"  # directory
   "$"
)
PROMPT=${(j::)prompt_components}
```

Or, you could let the `j` flag add the space delimiters, rather than putting them in the array:

```
# This is slightly different from the above, as it will put a space
# between the director and the $ (which IMO would look better).
# I leave it as an exercise to figure out how to prevent that.
prompt_components=(
 "%n@%m"  # username@hostname
 "$~"  # directory
 "$" 
)

PROMPT=${(j: :)prompt_components}
```